# Creation of the virtual directory http://localhost:1234/ failed with the error

Tags: visual-studio, iis-7

I'm trying to load a web-project in VS2013 and I get the following error.

Full Error: Creation of the virtual directory http:/ /localhost:1234/ failed with the error: The IIS Express applicationHost.config file contains invalid entries and must be corrected.

I've tried different numbers. If I use a portnumber that is configured in IIS I get the error that it's already configured for another webapplication

some of the relevant configuration:

```
<UseIISExpress>False</UseIISExpress>

<UseIIS>False</UseIIS>
<DevelopmentServerPort>1234</DevelopmentServerPort>
<DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
<IISUrl></IISUrl>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
For me, decrypting IISExpress folder (that one with 'config', 'Logs' and 'TraceLogFiles' subfodlers) solved this issue.

Comment: This worked for me.  @Demian-Kasier - you may want to acknowledge this answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Seconding that this also worked for me, upvoted for visibility